# How to pass arguments to a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to create a session with specific user email and password, for that I need to pass these two pieces of information to a pytest fixture as arguments.

My attempt to do so:

```
from pytest import fixture
from api_methods import ApiMethods


@fixture(scope="session")
def user_session():

    def _update_credentials(email, password):
        user_credentials = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        }
        return user_credentials

    session = ApiMethods()
    session.get_authorized(_update_credentials)
    return session
```

The problem is that **_update_credentials** returns a function object instead of JSON, which raises TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable

What sould I do to provide email and password to this fixture correctly? Help me, please :)

Comment: Generally pytest fixtures do not take arguments unless the args are other fixtures, see https://pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-request-other-fixtures  ...but it is possible to use the `mark` decorator to pass args from the test case to the fixture https://pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#using-markers-to-pass-data-to-fixtures

Answer (score 2):

What it seems you're trying to do is to use the [factory as fixture pattern](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html?highlight=fixture%20factory#factories-as-fixtures) like this:

```py
from pytest import fixture
from api_methods import ApiMethods


@fixture(scope="session")
def update_credentials():
    def _update_credentials(email, password):
        user_credentials = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        }
        return user_credentials

    return _update_credentials


@fixture(scope="session")
def user_session(update_credentials):
    user_credentials = update_credentials("email1", "password1")
    session = ApiMethods()
    session.get_authorized(user_credentials)

    return session
```

But it seems you could just do this instead:

```py
from pytest import fixture
from api_methods import ApiMethods


@fixture(scope="session")
def user_session():
    user_credentials = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    }
    session = ApiMethods()
    session.get_authorized(user_credentials)

    return session
```